# PostgreSQL how to append multiple results of execute query?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

I have a function `getitems(id)` which gives all rows that are relevant for this id.

I have a function in PostgreSQL named func1 which should return `getitems` over whole list of items:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(listof_id integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF newtype AS
$BODY$  

for item in listof_id:
    x=plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM getitems(%s)"%item)

return x;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

curently it returns x which contains the values of the last iteration (the `getitems` result of the last id in `listof_id`). How do I modify it so it will append each iteration to the last?

i tried to do :

```
x={}
for item in listof_id:
    x+=plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM getitems(%s)"%item)
```

and it doesn't work...

Comment: How big is *listof_id* ? You can modify/create a new  *getitems* to accept a list of IDs.

Comment: unknown. it can have 2 ids or 10000 ids. Modifying existing function is a last resort case... I would prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create or replace function func1(listof_id integer[])
  returns setof func_type as
$body$  

x = []
for item in listof_id:
    query = "select {0} as x, {0} * 2 as y, {0} * 3 as z, {0} * 4 as zz".format(item)
    result_set = plpy.execute(query)
    x.extend([[l['x'], l['y'], l['z'], l['zz']] for l in result_set])

return x
$body$ language plpythonu
;

select * from func1(array[1,2]);
 x | y | z | zz 
---+---+---+----
 1 | 2 | 3 |  4
 2 | 4 | 6 |  8
```